# How to Set Up AWS Beanstalk v3 Enhanced Health Multi-Container

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, healthd

while Amazon provides an example on how to set up enhanced health for Beanstalk Docker platform v2.x [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/samples/docker-multicontainer-v2.zip), I was unable to find an example for the latest Beanstalk platform v3. This is important since v2 expires in June 2022.

Basically, the main gap is the fact that v2 has an Nginx proxy which you can configure to write to the healthd logs. In v3, it's gone, even if you do specify Nginx as the proxy in the Beanstalk environment configuration.

What is the proper way to set this up?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?